# Unset not removing parameter from URL

Tags: joomla-3.x, router

I am writing a component with two views - a list view, and an article view.

The list view generates the links for each article as follows, with $text being the variable I want in the URL.

```
<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?Itemid=103&testvar=".strtolower($text)); ?>
```

ie http://www.test.com/test is the list page
and I want http://www.test.com/test/text as the article page

103 is the menu item id where the component is.  This is set to the list view.

My router contains the following code:

```
if(isset($query['testvar']))
    {        
     $segments[] = $query['testvar'];
     unset($query['testvar']);

    };
```

This generates the following URL:
http://www.test.com/test/text?testvar=text

`unset($query['testvar']);` does not seem to be working to remove the `?testvar=text` bit.  Everything else is working as expected.

A workaround would be `<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?Itemid=103")."/".strtolower($text); ?>` - but that seems hacky.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the JUri::delVar method:  https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Uri.Uri.html#method_delVar

```
JUri::delVar('testvar');
```

Worked perfectly for me :)

Comment: I don't see this as a "link-only answer"  It contained the one, single method call that is needed to do what OP wanted to do, JUri::delVar.  The link to the docs was for additional information :)

Comment: Sorry if I'm stepping on somebody's toes, not intended.  Been doing active developer support for 25+ years and sometimes there is only so much that can be said.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can only have one list view, then your `BuildRoute` function should have a maximum of 1 segment (which is the article alias). You should unset all other segments (try doing a `print_r` to see what you should unset.

In your `ParseRoute` function, you check for the count of segments, and you return either the list view or the article view. Here's how:

```
if (count($segments) == '0'){ //it's a list view
    `return array('option'=>'com_yourcomponent', 'view'=>'list', 'Itemid'=>[the item id of your choice]);`
else //it's an article view
    `return array('option'=>'com_yourcomponent', 'view'=>'article', 'testvar' => $segments[0], 'Itemid'=>[the item id of your choice]);`
```